# How to remove or hide Zenhub sidebar

Tags: github, styles, sidebar, kill, zenhub

When using [Zenhub](https://www.zenhub.com/) agile tool app within github domain, there is no way to hide the sidebar. If you spend a lot of time on the board this wasted screen real estate can be annoying.  How can I[image] hide it?

Answer (score 0):

Use Stylus [extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne/) or [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/) to kill the sidebar and use the [Zenhub Kill Sidebar theme](https://userstyles.org/styles/157717/zenhub-kill-sidebar)

And just enable the theme to toggle showing or hiding the sidebar.

Hooray no sidebar!
[image]